# Cannot add content (MapItemsControl) to an object of type "MapControl". Invalid Markup in designer

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm getting an error: Cannot add content to an object of type "MapControl" when trying to add MapItemsControl inside MapControl. This is Universal Windows App and whole project is compiling without any problems. App works but without designer I can't make my UI as I want...

Anyone had this problem? Is this some kind of VS bug? I'm using latest version of VS2015 Community BTW. I made a clean install of whole system(Win10) and this is fresh installation of VS. One thing I installed as plugin is ReSharper.

EDIT.
Added my XAML code as text. I deleted Grid and put DataTemplate. Still problem with adding MapItemsControl...

```
<Page
x:Class="SmartMachi_Win.Pages.Page1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SmartMachi_Win.Pages"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Near Me" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                   DataContext="{x:Bind Frame}" Visibility="{Binding PageTitleVisibility}" Margin="20,20,0,0" />
        <maps:MapControl x:Name="myMap" MapServiceToken="..."
                         Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" >
            <maps:MapItemsControl>
                <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="MapItemButton" Background="Transparent">
                            Test
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </maps:MapItemsControl>
        </maps:MapControl>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Changed ItemTemplate structure. Still problem with adding MapItemsControl...

Comment: Add your XAML to the question instead of a screenshot. That said, you certainly won't add a Grid directly to a MapItemsControl. Consider setting the MapItemsControl's ItemTemplate.

Comment: Question Edited. Added Xaml code and I made changes as you suggested but with no luck...

Answer (score 0):

You should have a XAML structure like this:

```
<maps:MapControl>
    <maps:MapItemsControl>
        <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                ...
            </DataTemplate>
        </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </maps:MapItemsControl>
</maps:MapControl>
```

Comment: Just a note, you should avoid posting your MapServiceToken to the public. Anybody can see (and use) it!

Comment: Ohh yeah thanks I did that before but forgot after edits.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with the implementation of MapControl. Basically you are not allowed to put a content inside a Control that has no ContentPropertyAttribute defined, which is the case for MapControl. The fact that your program runs and compiles is a runtime bug which is tracked within the Xaml team. In this case the designer is correctly complaining the error actually.

Comment: Ok so actually we can't put anything inside MapControl and designer is complaining error correctly but runtime bug allows control inside MapControl right? Hmm thats weird for me... Earlier version of map control allowed to put controls inside. So why we can't now???

Comment: @Zibiksior Let me retract what I have said. You cannot "directly" add a control inside a MapControl. The fact that it is fine in runtime is that there is a MapOverlayPresenter secretly added in between MapControl and the control inside it. You can see this by looking at the LiveVisualTree while debugging your app. Since that class is a private api, I believe there is an inconsistency between the runtime and the xaml designer.